# Typescript generics, new keyword in generics extends

Tags: typescript, generics

Was reading the TS docs about decorators and came across the following syntax:

```
   function classDecorator<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>(constructor:T) {
        return class extends constructor {
            newProperty = "new property";
            hello = "override";
        }
    }
```

I don't understand fully the following generics being used

```
<T extends {new(...args:any[]):{}}>
```

I do understand generics in general and also the `extends` keyword inside the generics. However I would like to now the meaning of the following syntax `{new(...args:any[]):{}}` and especially the use of the `new`, spread `...` operator and object literal syntax `{}` inside the generic expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{new(...args:any[]):{}}`
the overall meaning of this construct is the following:

"some object that has a constructor that takes a variable number of arguments of any type".

`...args` is a javascript (and hence the typescript) variable arguments declaration:

```
function f(...args: string[]) {}

f("asd", "a", "v")
```

the `{}` return type in this case, is just the literally empty object.

then the typescript `extend` loosens the constraints, for function params (as any function params combination really does extend `...args: any[]`)
and for the return type (since any object extends `{}`, and constructor implicitly returns the constructed object)

so this signature means: "give me anything that can create by `new` keyword, no matter how."

little [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGwCGAjAG2gF4oBvKBCAdwAoA6RnVAcyQC4ocEQBtAXQCUnMgF8oogFCTMBHEiRQAGuUlQomRCgzY4qBk1YcuPAYNXr1aiZKky5CqAE0LGrWizA9tAB6dtAJYILOZk0upSdgBm6AjYAYhQALY4ANYQAHI0ADwAKlAQPsAQCAAmivDIHtj4RAB8tABuOAScuaHWVNRQzQS0AIwANFAATMMAzIIA3LZQ0inpWXRKgpILmTS0TquSQA) on ts playground

Answer (score 3):

Its basically a class check (an object with a constructor)

`{new ... }`

These opening and closing curly braces indicate we are working inside an object. Like: `{num: number}`

```
new(...args: any[])
```

the `new` keyword here highlights that we are looking for something that has a constructor. The `...args: any[]` just state that this type doesn't care about the parameters of this constructor.

More specifically, `...args` with the three dots state there can be any number of parameters while `any[]` mean that these parameters can have the `any` type, meaning they can be absolutely anything.

Then:

```
: {}
```

This states that the constructor should return an object, which it most likely will if its for a class.

I've never seen it written like this, normally, its enough to just do this:

```
<T extends new (...args: any[])=>Object>
```

The reason the original one needed to be wrapped in `{...}` is because the usage of a colon `:` instead of an arrow `=>` confuses typescript, as it doesn't expect a colon outside of an object or type definition.

All in all, it makes sense you have this type, as it ensures this decorator can only be applied to a class, and types it as so within the decorator itself.